# rxjs how to return an obsevable and a value togethere in angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngx-bootstrap

within my angular app ; i'm using **ngx-bootstrap** modal.

this modal is used to return observable callbacks when modal shown and hidden (**`onShown`** / **`onHidden`**) after button click.

My code looks like this :

```
import {Injectable, TemplateRef} from '@angular/core';
import {BsModalService} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import {BsModalRef} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {

  }
  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template ,{ class: ' modal-lg' }  );
  }

  onModalShown(){
    return this.modalService.onShown;
    // I WANT TO RETURN this.modalService.onShown + modalRef


  onModalHidden(){
    return this.modalService.onHidden;
  }
}
```

My purpose i how can i combine the `onModalShown` /`onModalHidden` methods so that i may attach the reference to the modal `modalRef`  at same time with the `this.modalService.onShown` response ?

I WANT TO RETURN **this.modalService.onShown + modalRef** and be able within my component to subscribe on it and get both datas

```
@Component()
export class MyComponent {

constructor( private myService : MyService) {}

 whenCallbackFired(){
  this.myService.onModalShown.subscribe(()=>{
      GET HERE BOTH INFORMATIONS ??
  })
 }

}
```

To note ; `modalRef` is setted after some click on a button

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be enough:

```
onModalShown() {
  return this.modalService.onShown.pipe(
    map((directive) => ({ directive, modalRef: this.modalRef })
  );
}
```

Inside your component you can then do:

```
whenCallbackFired(){
  this.myService.onModalShown.subscribe(({ directive, modalRef })=> {
    console.log(modalRef);
  })
}
```